# Find the zero of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, cubics

Find the zero of the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 - 5x^2- 2x + 24,$ if it is given that the product of the zeroes is 12.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have one zero you can do polynomial division and then use the quadratic formula.  (this doesn't use information about the products of zeros, so there is probably a faster way if you know that)

Comment: Sorry it seems my zero of p(x) is incorrect as it is not working in the long division method.

Comment: No it's not,since by Bezout it follow that P(-2)=0,anyway you're dividing by $x+2$ not $x-2$

Comment: The product of the (three) zeroes of the cubic here must equal $-24$, not $12$.  The product of zeroes of a monic polynomial is always equal to plus or minus the constant term, the sign being determined by the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: Do you mean the product of the other zeros is $12$?

Comment: Perhaps what was meant was "... if it is given that the product of the _other two_ zeroes is 12"?

Comment: @MarkBennet and Henning, that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah it meant that the product of the two zeroes is 12 while the product of the three zeroes can be calculated as -24. Hence value of the third zero is -2. But when i divided the polynomial by x + 2, it didn't give the remainder as 0.

Comment: @user2468338, you must be making some small mistake in your division.  If you show us what you did, we can probably tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but I got the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by Bezout theorem if it was all ready told that roots are integers,other than that you could have tried plugging $(1,12),(2,6),(3,4)$ as the solution since product must be $12$
$$\frac{(x^3-5x^2-2x+24)}{x+2}=x^2-7x+12\\x_{1,2}=\frac{7\pm\sqrt{49-48}}{2}\\x_1=4,x_2=3,x_3=-2\\$$
Clearly product is $-24$ not $12$,maybe it was about positive roots?

Comment: Using Vieta's: $x_1x_2x_3=-24$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Ofc but not sure what it has to do with my answer

Comment: It's OK, your answer is fine.

Comment: Maybe the question meant that the product of two of its roots are given to be 12, then the idea might have been to divide -24 by 12 to obtain -2 is one of these roots, then you get a quadratic which is eas to solve

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to check for rational roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Let $P(x) = a_nx^n + ... + a_1x+a_0$. If $x=\frac{p}{q}$ is a root, with coprime $p$ and $q$, then

$$a_np^n+a_{n-1}p^{n-1}q + ... + a_1pq^{n-1} + a_0q^n = 0$$

Thus, $q$ must be a divisor of $a_n$ and $p$ a divisor of $a_0$.

Here, $a_n=1$ so any rational root must be an integer, and $a_0=24$, so if there is any integer root, it must be a divisor of $24$.

There are only a few possibilities: $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$, with plus or minus sign. So only a few checks to do. Once you get one root, you can reduce the degree by polynomial division.

---

As mentioned in the comments, here there is a faster way: with the extra hint that two of the three roots have product 12, since the product of the three roots is $-24$, that means the third root must be $-2$, so you can divide your polynomial by $x+2$ and find the two other either by the same reasoning, or by the quadratic formula.